# Form input check before submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have this modal form to get input from user. before submitting user form, i want to check if user enter their username, name, password, confirm password, status and scope. note that status is in radio button and scope is in check box.

But the problem i encounter now is that, the user still can click the button save and it doesn't check the condition as i describe above.

```
  <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="addUser" ng-submit="(addUser.username.$valid && addUser.name.$valid && addUser.password.$valid &&
                        addUser.confirmpassword.$valid && addUser.status.$valid && addUser.scope.$valid) ? add() : '';">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="hasError">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="setError(false);">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Error!</strong> {{errorMessage}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
                  <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                  <input class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required>
                  <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.username.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.name.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
                  <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                  <input class="form-control"  name="name" ng-model="user.name" required>
                  <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.name.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                           ng-model="user.password" required ng-minlength="5">
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"
                          ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
                    <label class="control-label" for="confirmpassword">Re-enter password</label>
                    <input type="confirmpassword" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword"
                           ng-model="user.confirmpassword" required ng-minlength="5">
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"
                          ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.status.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
                    <label for="status">Status</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.status" name="status" value="1"> Active
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.status" name="status" value="0"> Inactive<br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.scope.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
                    <label for="scope">Scope</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.scope.admin" name="scope[]" value="admin"> Admin <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.scope.app" name="scope[]" value="app"> App <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.scope.redemption" name="scope[]" value="redemption"> Redemption <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div ng-switch on="isLoading">
                    <div ng-switch-when="true">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block disabled">Saving ...</button>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="false">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="add();" >Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but looks like your ng-model is using an object 'user' for each property being captured whereas your ng-submit condition doesn't factor that in. Not sure if that's the issue but that's one thing you may want to check.

Also looks like you could do something like addUser.$valid instead of doing the full checks. You could also additionally try to disable the submit button by using

ng-disabled="addUser.$invalid".

Here's a tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation